# In NiFi, does converting data to an intermediary format (avro) brings any benefits if the output format is not Avro?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have NiFi flow that reads text data from CSV files, does some processing and then outputs the data to Kafka in JSON.
The processing step is mostly there to do data deduplication.

Here is a schema of the current flow:

```
Read CSV files ==> Processing (deduplication) ==> Convert to JSON ==> Push to Kafka
```

I'm thinking about converting the data to Avro after it's been read and then do the processing.

The proposed flow would be:

```
Read CSV files ==> Convert to Avro ==> Processing (deduplication) ==> Convert to JSON ==> Push to Kafka
```

Could this bring any benefits or is it just a useless intermediate step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would no reason to convert to Avro. You can configure PublishKafkaRecord with a CSV reader and a JSON writer to go right from CSV to JSON.

Comment: So, I'm assuming that when creating a Flowfile, NiFi parses the source data and loads it into its internal data format/structure. This is why mid-flow data format conversions are useless, unless you want to write the data to an external system (Kafka, Hadoop, etc...).

This would explains why it's not useful to convert to Avro in my flow.

Am I correct?

Comment: NiFi does not have an internal data format, the content of flow files is whatever bytes are used to the create the flow file, the bytes are written unchanged to nifi's content repository

Comment: The mid-flow conversion would require additional I/O and CPU to read the bytes out of the content repo, convert/parse in java, and write new bytes back out. If there was a reason that being in Avro helped then its fine, but why do this for no reason?